# change the figure reference style

Tags: cross-referencing

In fact, I have one figure containing 2 pictures. And I want to have a good looking design in term of referencing 
Here is the code:

```
   \immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
   \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}

   \usepackage{lineno}
   \modulolinenumbers[5]
   \usepackage{graphicx}


   \usepackage{subcaption}
   \usepackage{caption}


   \usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}

   \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
   \usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

   \journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

   \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}[!ht]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.182]{stack}
   \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip} 
   \caption{(a) the letter a, the letter b}
   \label{fig:letter}
   \end{figure}\par

   The \cref{fig:letter}a shows the letter a and \cref{fig:letter}b shows 
   the letter b
   \end{document}
```

[image]

I want the a next to fig.1 to be also blue like fig.1 and the same thing for fig.2 b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually adding `a` and `b` you could label your subfigures and let cleveref do the rest. As both your figures seems to be in a single graphic, you can use `\phantomsubcation` to create the labels.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}

\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
{
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1a}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1b}
}
\includegraphics[scale=0.182]{example-image}
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip} 
\caption{(a) the letter a, the letter b}
\label{fig:letter}
\end{figure}\par

The \cref{fig1a} shows the letter a and \cref{fig1b} shows 
the letter b
\end{document}
```

[image]